# Best practices about throwing exceptions from a remote service exposed via Spring's HTTP Invoker?

Tags: java, spring, remoting

Besides RemoteException and all of his subclases thrown for non business logic problems, what is the right way to handle business related exceptions? 
Is it OK to subclass RuntimeException in those cases? Should I keep my business exceptions being non-checked?

Answer (score 0):

I believe business logic exceptions are actually the only justified case for the checked exceptions, unlike lower level connectivity, database, file access, etc. exceptions.

Comment: So you that I can take as a general rule to use checked exceptions business logic exceptions, and any other non checked exception should be taken by the service client as an unhandleable/unrecoverable exception?

Comment: Checked vs Unchecked is the ongoing debate in Java world. Latest fashion, afaik, is to prefer unchecked everywhere whenever possible, so signatures of classes aren't changed when exception throws added/removed in lower levels. Checked exceptions are reserved for the most critical code scenarios, when it's necessary to see all the possible exceptions along all call-paths.

Comment: @rbajales: I believe this is an acceptable approach. But I personally would try to capture all runtime exceptions at the service level, the level of the business logic directly accessible from the client, and recast them as a single business logic exception, something like server error occurred while performing operation, maybe with more details in the exception message.

Comment: @Olaf - That is actually pretty critical to do since allowing implementation exceptions to get serialized to a client will likely cause serialization exceptions in the client.  They won't see the original exception anyway since the client is unlikely to have the implementations dependencies (and therefore the jars that define them).